# Grand Tours - Total Ascent (By stage, particularly the giro)

Tags: road-bike, climbing, racing

I'm looking for information on stages of grand tours, particularly the upcoming Giro.

I can find details of total distance by stage, and the amount of ascent on the key climbs of a stage, but I'm interested in the total ascent and distance by stage.

I can work it out for myself, if I can find an appropriate file with the route in. For example a GPX, KML, TCX etc, but I can't find them either.

Has anyone found a source for this information?

Comment: Good luck with this, I suspect you'll find this info difficult to get hold of (although presumably the teams themselves must have them). Please let us know if you're successful.

Comment: There was definitely one for the Tour de France on Google Earth a few years back. I am pretty sure it was KML.  I can't help more than that I am afraid

Answer (score 2):

I have found a site with a user who appears to have gone to considerable effort to plot and upload many stages of many tours, including Tour De France 2013 and Giro D'Italia 2013 and many others.

You can view his list here:

http://www.gpsies.com/trackList.do?username=Daniano

From my sampling, they appear to be pretty accurate, but, they are not official.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a little outdated, but for the Giro this year, there has been a map made for it - http://www.citalia.com/giro-ditalia

P.s. I appreciate an answer 2 year late probably isn't going to help, however I thought better late than never!